# Shopping questions

Tags: discussion

Are questions about where to purchase things (either equipment or ingredients or supplements or meals or anything else related to fitness and nutrition) on-topic or off-topic?

Answer (score 6):

Shopping questions are not on-topic here. They would either be closed as "not constructive" if the question is polling for recommendations. The shopping recommendation is also something that was highlighted on the [main Stack Exchange blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/):

> These questions may seem tolerable at first glance. Isn’t it our
>   mandate to help our fellow <s>ewoks</s>users? But consider the
>   voluminous amount of information you need to even *begin* properly
>   answering a shopping question:
>
> - What is your budget?
> - Where do you live?
> - What are your preferences?
> - Which alternatives will you consider?
> - When do you want to buy?

Even if all that information were provided, it is *too* specific to one's personal situation and would be closed as "too localized."

Asking *where* to shop for paleo diets sounds useful, but keep in mind that stores (whether online or physical) may not be permanent. They might move, they might close, products might change, and so on. Asking *what* to look for in a paleo diet would be a better start. Note that the [faq](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) states the nutrition unrelated to exercise is off-topic which is a separate matter in itself.

Comment: Also, questions like "How can I find a good XXX?" or "What should I look for when buying a new YYY?" are ok.